# Add an email attachment to WooCommerce notifications when order status is on-hold

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-attachments, email-notifications

In woocommerce I am using following code for adding PDF files as email attachment:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);

function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments , $id, $object ) {
    $your_pdf_path1 = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/pdf/ano1.pdf';
    $your_pdf_path2 = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/pdf/ano2.pdf';
    $attachments[] = $your_pdf_path1;
    $attachments[] = $your_pdf_path2;
    return $attachments;
}
```

My problem is that attachment is sending always for all email to customers. I would like to send email attachment only in case that Order status is "on-hold".

How is possible to know status of my order and send email attachment only for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Updated

You need to use the **`$id`** argument with 'customer_on_hold_order' as email ID in your function as a condition…

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);

function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments , $id, $object ) {

// Continue if it's customer_on_hold email notiication
if ( $id != 'customer_on_hold_order' ) return $attachments;

    $your_pdf_path1 = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/pdf/ano1.pdf';
    $your_pdf_path2 = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/pdf/ano2.pdf';
    $attachments[] = $your_pdf_path1;
    $attachments[] = $your_pdf_path2;
    return $attachments;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works

Comment: hmmm with your configuration I am not able to Order my product. When I click on "Order" button, I see only red rectangle and nothing inside. I used exactly your code and copied it to function.php. If I am using my code which I sent, it is working but not as I would like.

Comment: @RichardJacko Sorry I have make a little mistake… I have update the code. try it, now it should work as expected.

Comment: It is working properly now :) Really many thanks for help. Your code is perfect!!!

Comment: Today I found out that attachments were added only for payment via bank, but in case that user choose cash on delivery, attachments are not added. Please can you help what is necessary to add to code?